# the relationship between the tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, search

If a person is only interested in number theory, then he/she would just want to access only a few tags, such as number theory, elementary number theory, diophantine equation, etc. But if we select both “number-theory” and "elementary-number-theory" tags, then we will get the posts which tag both “number-theory” **and** "elementary-number-theory" :

> 663
>
> questions tagged
>
> (number-theory) (elementary-number-theory)

So the relationship between them is "**and**", I'd like to search the post which tag is "number-theory " **or** "elementary-number-theory", hence the relationship between them is "**or**", I wonder if one can do this ?

Comment: Currently the tags are just friends, but rumor has it that [number-theory] is going to change its Facebook to "It's complicated" and [elementary-number-theory] won't.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila You exactly answered my question in the title!

Comment: meta.SO: [Search (tag1) OR (tag2)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53943/search-tag1-or-tag2)

Comment: You can also use [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) to view questions from some set of tags. (But MathJax is not rendered in the titles there.)

Comment: See also [Filtering by tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/filtering-by-tag).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just tried putting `[number-theory] or [elementary-number-theory]` in the search box, and it seems to work.  I get 8,011 questions tagged
(number-theory) or  (elementary-number-theory).

Comment: that's ok,thank you!

Comment: What if I want to search for [number-theory] xor [elementary-number-theory]?

Comment: It is possible to exclude a tag from your search by preceding it with `-`. For example, you can search for `[number-theory] -[elementary-number-theory]` or the other way around. The `xor` syntax is not supported, possibly because there is no realistic use case for it.